# Getting a number from QString then converting it to integer

Tags: qt, integer, telnet, qstring

Iam developing a QT software which is using telnet commands to get some information from the adsl modem link.
i got all those information to a QString

```
 QString datarate = ui->output->toPlainText();
```

i want to select only a number
after downstream rate

```
Downstream rate = 10239 Kbps
```

and convert it to integer to compare it with other numbers ...
i don't want to take the first one which is = 20892 kbps

```
Status: Showtime
Max:    Upstream rate = 1193 Kbps, Downstream rate = 20892 Kbps

Bearer: 0, Upstream rate = 1021 Kbps, Downstream rate = 10239 Kbps
```

any advices??
note : the number will be random so adsl status are much different

Comment: Are you asking how to parse a long string of text and extract just that particular number that you're interested in?

Comment: yep exactly bro , then i want to compare it with other numbers ..

Comment: your message structure is always like the sample?

Comment: yes the text is the same only the numbers different , every adsl user has his/her special downstream rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work:

```
QString datarate = ui->output->toPlainText();
int number = datarate.split("Downstream rate = ")[2].split(" ")[0].toInt();
```

This is taking the following steps:

1. Breaking up the string into pieces separated by "Downstream rate = "
2. Taking the third string in that list (Should contain "10239 Kbps")
3. Splitting that by space characters and taking the first token. (Should contain "10239")
4. Finally converting the string to an int.

Comment: Thank you so much bro <3 i will try that , i am sure it's the rightest algorithm ... many thanks really <3